# O_DIRECT flag for files

Tags: c++, c, database, linux

There's a famous Linus' quote, saying that `O_DIRECT` is useless, or even hell.

If one has a super-strong demands for speed, really there is `no` scenario for a reasonable use of this flag for regular files in Linux?

**Edit:** What about "write-only" access to log files?

Comment: What gave you the idea that `O_DIRECT` is good for speed?

Comment: Possibly useful link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/use-of-o-direct-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming write throughput is much more deterministic with `O_DIRECT` than without.  It's a godsend.

Compare the streaming write throughput you get from writing to a high-speed disk array's block device (something like a theoretical hw capability) to the throughput you get to a file on a filesystem on that same array.  Make sure you use a filesystem which has good streaming write performance (`xfs` is one, some of the other modern ones may be as well).  Then put `O_DIRECT` in and see what happens.  Every kernel release + disk array I've evaluated has exhibited signficant differences (a much wider sd without `O_DIRECT` than with).

EDIT: to be fair, I've never compared `write` on an `O_DIRECT` fd with `mmap`/`madvise`.

Comment: Really? Could you please add some details?

Answer (score 3):

You can get similar effects with fdatasync and posix_fadvise( advice=POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED.

fdatasync just gets your data on to the disc, but does not get it out of the cache.

If you're writing a log file at an extreme rate (and almost never read it), the pages of the log file can often push more useful pages out of the buffer cache. This is not desirable. With O_DIRECT they won't though.

But to achieve a similar effect, you can use the posix_fadvise to ask the kernel to discard any cached pages for a given range of a given file (or all of it if you like).

If, for example, you are writing a high-writes database, and your transaction log is filling up at 10 Mb / sec, you might want to get rid of the cached pages every 100M or something, to allow the memory to be more usefully used by other things.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a major concern, you might use [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) with [madvise](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) and possibly [readahead](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readahead) (for a disk file).

But I would really like to understand what kind of application demands that.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get the same consistency effects by using `fdatasync` or the Linux-specific `sync_file_range`.

Comment: Consistency maybe is not a major reason, perhaps skipping kernel buffers could be a more important factor.

Comment: @James: Maybe back in the bad old days. I haven't heard of any performance benefits in Linuxes from the last three years.

Comment: Great, we'd like to omit `O_DIRECT` completely, so I'd like to be sure that we won't miss anything

Comment: @James: As always, benchmark it yourself to be sure you have the best implementation.